# Stop a corona collision event from firing multiple times

Tags: sdk, coronasdk

So I only want my collision listener to fire once. I've tried putting in if execute variables but it's not exactly elegant.

```
local function collideGround( self, event ) 
        local obj  = event.other 
        local phase = event.phase        
        if ( phase == "began" ) then             
            if obj == ground then
                print("Hit")

            end

        elseif ( phase == "ended" ) then



        end
        return true
    end
    player.collision = collideGround
    player:addEventListener( "collision", player )
```

Comment: Could you please update your question to indicate what you're asking? Does this code work and you're trying to make it more elegant? Is the code not working in some way?

Comment: It does work but I want a way for the collision listener to only fire once,it is currently firing multiple times

Answer (score 0):

collision listener is not something like a touch event or tap event. whenever your player object awakes from a collision event, `collideGround` will be called and that's why they provided us three different `event.phase`.

Any collision event handler that returns true will stop further propagation of that collision event, even if there are further listeners that would otherwise have received it. This allows you to further limit the number of events that are created and passed to the Lua side. While individual events are not very expensive, large numbers of them can affect overall performance, so limiting event propagation is a good practice.

I think [Collision Detection](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.coronalabs.com%2Fdaily%2Fguide%2Fphysics%2FcollisionDetection%2Findex.html&ei=j9JeVc6kKMuhNv-JgJgM&usg=AFQjCNHyN3-jqyLgvOXG9HW19rERPPp1Bg&sig2=bSuYJksCIZ8OPiOGJ2gSkw&bvm=bv.93990622,d.eXY) will help you somehow achieve your goal.